# Remove "-template" part from multiple filenames in linux

Tags: linux, bash, pattern-matching, rename, filenames

I have some files with names like:

```
jcr-repository-template.xml
imapserver-template.xml
```

and I would like to rename them as:

```
jcr-repository.xml
imapserver.xml.
```

I tried to use `find -name "*-template.*"  -exec rename -v "template" ""  {} ";"`

It worked but I only matched the "template" and not "-template" (I couldn't find how). So now I have one dash character at the end of each filename. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many commands option `--` can be used to indicate the end of options i could test and it worked:

```
touch imapserver-template.xml
rename -v -- -template '' imapserver-template.xml
```

otherwise another solution can be to use an equivalent regex pattern which doesn't start with `-`

```
rename -v '(?:-template)' '' imapserver-template.xml
```

Comment: Thank you! I used find -name "*-template.*"  -exec rename -v -- -template '' {} ";" as you said and it worked!